# Find all solutions on $\Bbb R$ to the differential equation $y' = 3|y|^{2/3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions on $\Bbb R$ to the differential equation $y' = 3|y|^{2/3}$

$\mathbf{Solution:}$ First observe that $|y|^{2/3} = \left({|y|^2}\right)^{1/3}= y^{2/3}$. We proceed by separation of variables: 
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = 3 |y|^{2/3} = 3 y^{2/3}
\implies (y^{-2/3})dy = 3 dx
$$
Integrating both sides gives us that
$$\int (y^{-2/3})dy = \int 3 dx \implies  3 y^{1/3}= 3x + k \implies y = (x + c)^3
$$
 Does this answer the question? Seems a little too easy..

Comment: I think that you considered $|y|^{2/3}$ instead of $|y|^{3/2}$, but other than that it seems fine!

Comment: Yes I titled it wrong. Is the answer to the statement the last line I wrote? Is that okay to write all solutions on $R$ this way?

Comment: Yes it is. Another way to write is that all the solutions of this ODE are of the form $y(x) = (x+C)^3$, where $y :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is pretty right. If you don't like the method of separation of variables, you can do the following:
$$ y' = 3y^{2/3} $$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}$:

\begin{align} \frac{1}{3}y'y^{-2/3} &= 1 \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y^{1/3}\right) &= 1 \end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align} y^{1/3} &= x+C \\ y &= (x+C)^3\end{align}

Therefore the solutions (aside from $y(x) \equiv 0$) are the functions $y:\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto (x+C)^3 \in \mathbb{R}$, for every $C\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, the last line is what I was looking for.

Comment: You have missed the zero solution.No value oc C will provide this solution though.